# Rails 3 annotate doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, annotate

When I run `annotate` at the command-line, I get the following error:

```
$ annotate
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks': undefined method `task' for #<MyApp::Application:0x00000102e03b90> (NoMethodError)
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/annotate-2.4.0/lib/annotate.rb:17:in `load'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/annotate-2.4.0/lib/annotate.rb:17:in `load_tasks'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/annotate-2.4.0/bin/annotate:66:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/annotate:19:in `load'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/annotate:19:in `<main>'
```

This is what my Gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'

gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git'
gem 'mime-types', :require => 'mime/types'

gem 'rails3-generators'

gem 'devise',  '~> 1.1.3'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 0.3.4'

gem 'declarative_authorization', :git => 'git://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization.git'

gem 'aasm'
gem 'braintree'

#For voting
gem 'thumbs_up'

# For In-Place-Editing
gem 'best_in_place'

#For slugs for the plans
gem "friendly_id", "~> 3.2"

gem 'aws-s3'

group :development do
    # Server
    gem 'thin'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
    #gem 'rails-erd'
    gem 'annotate'
    gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
    gem 'ruby_parser'
end
```

This is all on my localhost btw.

Comment: Ran `bundle update` and that seems to have fixed this issue. It didn't before, so not sure why. Leave it up to Rails to make a fool of me :|

Answer (score 0):

Marcamillion, it probably broke because at one stage you had rake 0.9.0 installed, which broke a lot of  things for a lot of people without deprecating methods or warning people. When you ran bundle update, it would have installed rake 0.9.2 which fixed this. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem using `gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0"`.

I'm using ruby 1.9.2p320 and Rails 3.2.13.